# InetAddress.getByName, UnknownHostException on some devices

Tags: android, inetaddress

In an Android app executing the following piece of code to determine if a hostname is present in my network:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfHostnames.size(); i++) {
     //noinspection unused
     String hostname = listOfHostnames.get(i).getAddress();
     try {
      InetAddress test = InetAddress.getByName(listOfHostnames.get(i).getAddress());
      //noinspection unused
      String testHost1 = test.getHostAddress();
      Logging.logw("Found", testHost1);
     } catch (Exception e) {
      Logging.logw(e.getClass() + " InetAddress EX", e.getMessage());
      continue;
     }
     //.....
}
```

It works on most devices i tested, but it fails on a Samsung Galaxy Tab-A (SM-T550) with this following exception (hostname isn't that one):

> W/class java.net.UnknownHostException InetAddress EX: Unable to resolve host "hostname-abc": No address associated with hostname

Do Samsungs need some extra code,or is there another way to check if a hostname is present on the network?

**EDIT**

listOfHostnames is a list of objects, where the getAddress method returns hostnames, such has "BrandT-12-28183" (the type of hostnames the devices using have)

I also have these permissions declared on the manifest:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> ```

Comment: Sir, is it need permission for that??

Comment: i have     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
if thats what you are asking

Comment: just i doubt on that

Comment: did try to off and on wifi

Comment: yes, i tried that

Comment: You may need to check the DNS settings for the failing devices, as `getByName` will probably do a DNS lookup for each of the provided hostnames.